# Reading several files into an associative array in bash (>4.0)

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

I am new to associative arrays in bash so please forgive me if I sound silly somewhere. Let's say am reading through a large file and using bash (version = 4.2.46) associative array to store FDR values for genes. For one file, I am simply doing:

```
declare -A array

while read ID GeneID geneSymbol chr strand exonStart_0base exonEnd upstreamES upstreamEE downstreamES downstreamEE ID IJC_SAMPLE_1 SJC_SAMPLE_1 IJC_SAMPLE_2 SJC_SAMPLE_2 IncFormLen SkipFormLen PValue FDR IncLevel1 IncLevel2 IncLevelDifference; do 
    array[$geneSymbol]="${array[$geneSymbol]}${array[$geneSymbol]:+,}$FDR" ; 
done < input.txt
```

Which will store the FDR values that I can print by doing

```
    for key in "${!array[@]}"; do echo "$key->${array[$key]}"; done 

# Prints out
"ABHD14B"->0.285807588279,0.898327660004,0.820468496328
"DHFR"->0.464931314555,0.449582575347
...
```

I naively tried to read several file through my array by doing

```
declare -A array

find ./aligned.filtered/rMAT*/MATS_output/SE.MATS.JunctionCountOnly.txt  -type f -exec cat {} + | 

while read ID GeneID geneSymbol chr strand exonStart_0base exonEnd upstreamES upstreamEE downstreamES downstreamEE ID IJC_SAMPLE_1 SJC_SAMPLE_1IJC_SAMPLE_2 SJC_SAMPLE_2 IncFormLen SkipFormLen PValue FDR IncLevel1 IncLevel2 IncLevelDifference; 
do  array[$geneSymbol]="${array[$geneSymbol]}${array[$geneSymbol]:+,}$FDR" ;  
done
```

But in this case my array ends up being empty. I can of course cat all the files I need and save them into a single file that I can use as above, but it would be nice to know how to make an associative array to store data from several distinct files.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be doing this in `bash` in the first place, but your main problem is that the `while` loop runs in a *subshell* induced by the pipeline. Use process substitution to invert the relationship.

(Also, don't give names to all the fields you don't actually use; just split the line into an indexed array and pick out the two fields you actually want.)

```
while read -a fields; do
  geneSymbol=${fields[1]}
  FDR=${fields[...]}   # some number; i'm not counting
  array[$geneSymbol]="${array[$geneSymbol]}${array[$geneSymbol]:+,}$FDR"
done < <(find ./aligned.filtered/rMAT*/MATS_output/SE.MATS.JunctionCountOnly.txt  -type f -exec cat {} +)
```

`find` probably isn't necessary; just put your `while` loop inside a `for` loop:

```
for f in ./aligned.filtered/rMAT*/MATS_output/SE.MATS.JunctionCountOnly.txt; do
  while read -a fields; do
    ...
  done < "$f"
done
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of process substitution! It worked, thanks!